# Unable to show a list of all the sub sites under a parent sub site

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, content-search-web-part

I have team site collection, where I created a parent sub site. Then under the parent sub site I created many sub sites.
Now I need inside the parent sub site to show a list of all sub sites under it.

I tried the following 2 approaches, but none of them worked:-

- I added a “Table of Content” web part , under the “content Rollout” Category, but the result is that all the content will be displayed , not only the sub sites, also I can not sort them by created date or show created by ..
- I added a “content Search” web part , and select “only return site” under the Keyword filter drop down as mentioned on this [link](https://jamesdiblasi.wordpress.com/2013/12/05/display-subsites-in-a-webpart/)  , as follow, but nothing was displayed.

So can anyone advice on this please ?

Comment: For the search query you need to remove the "isdocument..." And the part that ends with "STS_ListItem" to make it find your sites

Comment: Try adding a `*` at the end of the `path`

Comment: ok i tried this <<path:"http://tvstg01/templete*"   contentclass:STS_Web >> & this <<path:"http://tvstg01/templete /*"   contentclass:STS_Web>> but did not work ... can u adivce please?

Comment: @RobertLindgren do u have any idea about this ??